# Skip row if a record exists in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a translation application where users can translate strings, however I need to skip the rows that the user has already translated which all translations are stored in another table by users.

Basically it should skip until a string is found that has not been translated by the user, but my SQL does not perform this since it still picks up records that the user has already translated.

The SQL:

```
SELECT strings.key,
       strings.string
FROM
(
    app_language_strings strings

    INNER JOIN est8_languages lang ON strings.language_id = lang.lang_id AND lang.lang_format = 'french' AND strings.admin_string = 0
)
WHERE strings.string_id NOT IN ( SELECT trans.string_id FROM app_translations trans WHERE trans.user_id = 5 ) 
LIMIT 0, 1
```

As you can see I put in the `NOT IN` syntax, but this doesn't exclude rows, how can I do this?

Comment: which tables here have user_id ??

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a new boolean column named something like "translated"? Then you simply do "SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE translated = FALSE" and you only get non translated results back. With this approach, you could also mark already translated strings that need to be retranslated again.

Comment: Nope, there will be other users translating each string, overall I will be using the translations from the translations table for comparison between translations before the decision is final (having picking out the best translation). Having one translation per string is not applicable. Good suggestion but I would have done this if it was one translation per string.

Comment: Ok, then how about having "temporary" table with just three values; userID, translationID and translation. You can quickly get multiple translations back (using translationID) while avoiding inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT * FROM strings WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM translated_strings WHERE id=strings.id )
```

Comment: MySQL 5.5 has the `EXISTS` subquery syntax as stated in the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).